# REPLAYGAIN value being ignored on some MP3's - FFmpeg Transcoder cs - process Error Data Received:454

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, mp3, replaygain

I am having an issue per below. I use Windows, and just installed ffmpeg-2024-03-07-git-97beb63a66-full_build, which did not correct it.

I have added Track ReplayGain to my music library using Foobar.

I am having issues with FFMpeg not taking the ReplayGain value into account when Transcoding some MP3's, all seeming to be ones purchased versus ones I ripped. The issue is on less than 1% of my files.

I set my library to ReplayGain by Track, and, as a troubleshooting step, also had Foobar process Album RG value for the culprits.

The files in question work fine when playing directly in Foobar, taking the ReplayGain value into account with no spikes.

But, when using FFMpeg, the ReplayGain value is ignored for a small percentage of MP3's.

For 99% of my collection, FFMpeg transcodes the new MP3 for me, and the new file is substantially quieter, as expected and desired per the negative ReplayGain value (or louder for the handful that have a positive value).

But, for some, the newly Transcoded file is the exact same loud volume, creating a spike when played, despite the ReplayGain value being present, being 3 times louder than it should be.

Since these are sourced from commercial sources,It is almost like these MP3's are copyrighted and, thus FFMpeg cannot alter the volume when Transcoding. But, when looking, the copyright tag is set to No.

I am using MyMedia for Alexa to play my media via my Echo devices, so it, not me, is generating the commands to FFMpeg, then playing the resulting Transcoded MP3's.

I desire to know what the issue is with these files. Even if I cannot fix the issue with transcoding, it would be good to have a way to search for the culprits via a MP3 tag criteria so I can then convert them to WAV and back to MP3 in the hopes the ReplayGain would then work.  But, I have no clue what the bottleneck is, or what FFMpeg does not like.

MyMedia for Alexa provides the following log, giving me a Processing Data error 454, which I could not find info on.

Interesting, though, I realized as I type this.  The files that do not get transcoded, MyMedia sends:

```
FFmpegTranscoder.cs:CreateTranscodeStream:358 FFMpegTranscoder::OnTranscodeStream -  Commandline = -i "K:\Hornsby, Bruce\2009-07-25 - Asheville, NC - Biltmore House\bh090725d3_01_Lady_With_a_Fan.mp3" -movflags +faststart -codec copy "C:\Program Files\MyMediaForAlexa\TranscodeCache\i5ratntg.co1.mp3"
```

But, for the correctly processed files:

```
FFMpegTranscoder::OnTranscodeStream -  Commandline = -i "K:\Simon, Paul\For Kathy [vinyl]\10.Waiting For Art.mp3" -ab 384k -ac 2 -vn -f mp3 -af volume=replaygain=track "C:\Program Files\MyMediaForAlexa\TranscodeCache\sxb15ked.zf2.mp3"
```

So:

`-movflags +faststart -codec copy`

versus:

`-ab 384k -ac 2 -vn -f mp3 -af volume=replaygain=track`

Even though both have a ReplayGain value, why would FFMpeg need the parameters one way for one file but not the other. I want all in the latter.

any ideas from someone?  Thanks!

```
10/03/2024 16:27:44.137 11624:0 51 FFmpegTranscoder.cs:process_ErrorDataReceived:454 FFMpegTranscoder::OnTranscodeStream - 2568 Debug: ffmpeg version 2024-03-07-git-97beb63a66-full_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2024 the FFmpeg developers
```

[could not include entire log due to sizing limitations so hopefully this is enough info]

Comment: I did a side by side comparison of which files were being processed using the Regain value, and which were not. I found the solution.  The issue was that MyMedia for Alexa uses the ID3V1 tag info if it exists, else it uses the ID3V2 tagging info.  ID3V1 does not include regain info. There is no way I saw to change which info to default to (ED3V1 or ID3V2), so, I used software to simply remove the ID3V1 tags, reprocessed the files in MyMedia for Alexa, and now all works as expected.

Comment: Please add an answer if you solved it yourself.